# Injecting service with $http messes up controller

Tags: angularjs

I made a service that's using $http to post login data and get authentication token, but whenever i inject it into the controller, it breaks (looks like html doesnt see it). When I remove the service injection, or inject one using $resource instead, everything works fine.
Here's the code for the service:

```
    MyApp.service('LoginSrv', ['$http', function User($http) {
         var userData = {
         isAuthenticated: false,
         username: '',
         bearerToken: '',
         expirationDate: null,
      };

    function setHttpAuthHeader() {
          $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + userData.bearerToken;
        }

     this.getUserData = function(){
         return userData;
};

this.authenticate = function(username, password, successCallback, errorCallback) {
      var config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/accounts/login',
            headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
        data: 'grant_type=password&username=' + username + '&password=' + password,
      };

  $http(config)
    .success(function(data) {
          userData.isAuthenticated = true;
          userData.username = data.userName;
          userData.bearerToken = data.access_token;
          userData.expirationDate = new Date(data['.expires']);
          setHttpAuthHeader();
          if (typeof successCallback === 'function') {
                successCallback();
              }
        })
    .error(function(data) {
          if (typeof errorCallback === 'function') {
                if (data.error_description) {
                      errorCallback(data.error_description);
                    } else {
                  errorCallback('Unable to contact server; please, try again later.');
                }
          }
    });
};
  }]);
```

And here is the controller code:

```
    MyApp.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, LoginSrv)
{
    $scope.loginUsername = 'Jan';
    $scope.loginPassword = 'Maria';
    $scope.userLogin = new LoginSrv();
    $scope.loginError = false;
    function onSuccesfulLogin () {};
    function onFailedLogin(error) {};
    $scope.login = function () {
        userLogin.authenticate($scope.loginUsername, $scope.loginPassword, onSuccesfulLogin, onFailedLogin);
    }; 

});
```

Comment: what error are you receiving? what do you mean html doesn't see it?

Comment: Why are you doing `function User($http)` as opposed to just `function($http)`?

Comment: Also why are you mixing injection styles? In your controller you are using direct injection, but in your service you are using minification-friendly injection.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: By breaks i mean, that i have {{loginUsername}} and {{loginPassword}} in my html, and after injecting the service they dont show me the values of the scope variables anymore.

User function () was just a copy-paste mistake, the core of the code is taken from the tutorial. Unfortunetly it doesn't resolve the matter.

And for mixing injection styles - thanks for pointing it out, i've tried the minification-friendly way to check if it would resolve my problem, but it didn't.

Comment: In which case angular has thrown an exception and essentially crashed. Look in the browsers console to see exactly what that exception is. Also you don't need to use callbacks, return the http call (`return $http()`) and use angulars promises.

Comment: Error: LoginSrv is not a constructor

Comment: You calling `new LoginSrv()` you can't do that. Services are singletons, just use it directly. Angular will instantiate them for you and share a single instance accross your app. You should look into factories if you need to create new instances. However your factory will return the new object, but you can create it yourself in the factory.

Answer (score 1):

[Services are singleton so you need not give a "new"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services),

I Made a brief example of the same flow you need and worked well, I hope to help:

> The Service

```
angular.module("yourapp").factory('LoginSrv', function User($http) {
        var _authenticate = function(username, password) { 
          console.log('logged') 
        };
        return {
            authenticate: _authenticate
        };
});
```

> The Controller

```
angular.module("yourapp").controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, LoginSrv)
        {
            $scope.loginUsername = 'Jan';
            $scope.loginPassword = 'Maria';
            $scope.userLogin = LoginSrv;
            $scope.loginError = false;
            $scope.login = function () {
                userLogin.authenticate($scope.loginUsername, $scope.loginPassword);
            }; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer does a good job of explaining your `LoginSrv` related exception and explains how implement a service/factory. However what it fails to note is the differences between the two.

**Factory** 
When injecting a factory you will be provided with the *return value* as a result of *invoking* the factory function.

**Service**
When injecting a service you will be provided with an *instance* of the service function. That is akin to `new serviceFunction();`. It is important to note angular will do this the first time the service is injected, all others times it is injected you will receive the same instance.

So Factories are meant for object creation (hence the name) and services are meant, well, for services. So shared logic.

So in my opinion (that's all it is) your existing service is trying to do both. You appear to have a user object that your wanting to create but also methods for authenticating a user. It would be best to put that user object in a factory which returns a create method to create a new user. Then put the authentication logic in a service. Then your authentication is not directly coupled to your user implementation.

Possible Implementation (pseudo code)

```
.factory('userFactory', function () {
    return {
        create: function (details) {
            return Object.create({}, {
                username: {
                    value: details.username
                },
                password: {
                    value: details.password
                },
                isAuthenticated: {
                    value: false
                }
            });
        }
    }  
});

.service('auth', function ($http) {
    this.authenticate = function (username, password) {
        //Build config
        return $http();
    }
});

.controller('test', function ($scope, userFactory, auth) {
    var user =  userFactory.create({
        username: 'hiya',
        password: 'epic secrets'
    });

    auth.authenticate(user.username, user.password)
        .then(function (d) {
            user.isAuthenticated = d.isAuthenticated;
        })
        .catch(SomeGenericErrorHandler);
});
```

any questions just ask